# Membership.GetUser() within TransactionScope throws TransactionPromotionException

Tags: c#, linq, transactions, asp.net-membership

The following code throws a `TransactionAbortedException` with message "The transaction has aborted" and an inner `TransactionPromotionException` with message "Failure while attempting to promote transaction":

```
    using ( TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope() )
    {
        try
        {
            using ( MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext() )
            {
                Guid accountID = new Guid( Request.QueryString[ "aid" ] );
                Account account = ( from a in context.Accounts where a.UniqueID.Equals( accountID ) select a ).SingleOrDefault();
                IQueryable < My_Data_Access_Layer.Login > loginList = from l in context.Logins where l.AccountID == account.AccountID select l;

                foreach ( My_Data_Access_Layer.Login login in loginList )
                {
                    MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser( login.UniqueID );
                }

                [... lots of DeleteAllOnSubmit() calls]

                context.SubmitChanges();
                transactionScope.Complete();
            }   
        }

        catch ( Exception E )
        {
        [... reports the exception ...]
        }
    }
```

The error occurs at the call to `Membership.GetUser()`.

My Connection String is:

```
      <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Everything I've [read](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/aspnet_answers/NETFrameworkASPNETwebcontrols/Jun2006/post27037786.asp) tells me that `TransactionScope` should just get magically applied to the Membership calls. The user exists (I'd expect a null return otherwise.)

Comment: What does `GetUser` do? If you are merely querying for things, what is the need of `TransactionScope`?

Comment: GetUser() is part of the Microsoft Membership API. I've deleted a lot of code that follows that deletes all logins for an account then the account itself, for readability's sake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TransactionScope` class masks exceptions.  Most likely what's happening is that something inside that scope is failing (throwing an exception), and the `TransactionAbortedException` is simply a side-effect that occurs when control exits the `using` block.

Try wrapping everything inside the `TransactionScope` in a `try-catch` block, with a rethrow inside the `catch`, and set a breakpoint there; you should be able to see what the real error is.

One other thing, `TransactionScope.Complete` should be the last statement executed before the end of the `using` block containing the `TransactionScope`.  In this case you should probably be alright, since you're not actually doing any work afterward, but putting the call to `Complete` inside an inner scope tends to make for more bug-prone code.

---

**Update:**

Now that we know what the inner exception is (failure promoting transaction), it's more clear what's going on.

The problem is that inside the `TransactionScope`, you are actually opening up another database connection with `GetUser`.  The membership provider doesn't know how to re-use the `DataContext` you already have open; it has to open its own connection, and when the `TransactionScope` sees this, it tries to promote to a distributed transaction.

It's failing because you probably have MSDTC disabled on either the web server, the database server, or both.

There's no way to avoid the distributed transaction if you are going to be opening two separate connections, so there are really a few ways around this issue:

1. Move the `GetUser` calls *outside* the `TransactionScope`.  That is, "read" the users first from the membership provider into a list, then start the transaction when you actually need to start making modifications.
2. Remove the `GetUser` calls altogether and read the user information directly from the database, on the same `DataContext` or at least the same connection.
3. Enable DTC on all servers participating in the transaction (performance will be impacted when a transaction promotes).

I think that option #1 is going to be the best in this scenario; it's very unlikely that the data you need to read from the membership provider will be changed between the time you read it and the time you begin the transaction.

Comment: Another valuable insight! I've already got a try-catch block *outside* the using block. I'll move it inside, edit my code above accordingly then report back shortly.

Comment: ... nope. Still the same exception, same line. Of note -- commenting out the TransactionScope and it works fine. Also of note -- inner exception message "Failure while attempting to promote transaction"

Comment: @Bob Kaufman: Actually, that inner exception is the important one.  Will explain why in a moment...

Comment: I successfully went with option #2. Thank you! #1 isn't practical; I'm selecting an "Account" then enumerating over and deleting all the Logins under that account. #3 - we're both in agreement that this is bad news on many levels.

Comment: I have DTC enabled on the server but I am still getting this error when calling a web method. Does anyone have any idea why? Basically I did 3 on the list and 1 or 2 don't apply to me and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Para, if a large part of this answer doesn't apply to you then it sounds like you need to ask a new question. Neither I nor anyone else can be of any help to you given so little information.

Comment: @Aaronaught Hi, yes I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195925/nhibernate-and-transactionscope-transaction-aborted-spontaniously

Answer (score 1):

At one level, it is correct; the transaction is always aborted (you aren't calling Complete()). Is that the exact code?

Additionally, having the `DataContext` *outside* the `TransactionScope` makes me suspect that it might be doing some odd things since the transaction isn't there when the data-context first gets created. Have you tried (both of):

- reversing the creation order, so the `TransactionScope` spans the `DataContext`
- calling `Complete`

?

```
using ( TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope() )
using ( MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext() )
{
    /* ... */
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: I've transposed the TransactionScope and DataContext controls per your suggestion, here and in my code, to no avail. I've also added the call to Complete() as in my code to better reflect my code without introducing a ***lot*** of noise from my original source.